# Regain control of window after popup in Vue

Tags: vue.js, popup, popupwindow, vue-composition-api

Im doing a proyect in vue composition API and I open a popup because im integrating myself with a provider.

This provider asks me to open a popup, make a form with certain data and then POST it to a url. This way the provider gains control of the pop up and does there thing. The problem its that after finishing in a not happy path way, the provider redirects my main window to another page and i dont want that, i want to keep control of my main window (giving the provider controll only of the pop up).

This is my code and basically I want to keep control of the main window after the pop up does its thing:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const PopUpInsertValue = (data: IData) => {
  if (!popupWindow.value) {
    return;
  }
  const popupDocument = popupWindow.value.document;
  const form = popupDocument.createElement('form');
  form.id = 'postForm';
  form.action = data.some_url;
  form.method = 'POST';

  const inputFields = [
    { name: 'action', value: 'inicio' },
    ...
  ];
  inputFields.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    const input = popupDocument.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = name;
    input.value = value;
    form.appendChild(input);
  });

  const submitButton = popupDocument.createElement('input');
  submitButton.type = 'submit';
  submitButton.value = 'Submit';
  submitButton.style.display = 'none';
  form.appendChild(submitButton);

  // Append the form to the body and submit it
  popupDocument.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
};

const popupWindow = ref<Window | null>(null);

popupWindow.value = open(
 '',
  "SuperPopUp",
  `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=600,height=600,left=100,top=100`
);
PopUpInsertValue(data: IData);
</script>
```